Closed form of the integral $\int_{0}^{1} \log^n \left (\frac {1-x}{1+x}\right )dx$
I found this nice integral
$$i=\int_{0}^{1} \log^3\left (\frac {1-x}{1+x}\right)\;dx\tag{1}$$
on youtube but I don't remember where.
Let us generalize a bit to a power $n=0, 1, 2, ...$ and ask for the closed expression of this integral
$$i(n) = \int_{0}^{1} \log^n \left (\frac {1-x}{1+x} \right )\;dx\tag{2}$$
Hints
It might be worthwhile to
(a) study the corresponding integral
$$d(t) = \int_{0}^{1} \left (\frac {1-x}{1+x}\right )^{t}\;dx\tag{3}$$
from which $i(n)$ can be generated by differentiating with respect to $t$ at $t=0$, and
(b) to calculate the generating function of the $i(n)$
$$g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}i(n) z^n\tag{4}$$
Comment after accepting a solution
There were two excellent solutions to my question, and it was hard for me to decide which one I should accept.
Writing the solution in this form
$$i(n) = (-1)^{n} 2n!\left(1-2^{1-n}\right)\zeta(n)\tag{5}$$
let me just add some remarks related to my hints.
Hint 1 was used in the solution of Mark Viola.
Hint 2 was misleading, as the sum $(4)$ is not convergent.
We have to study instead the exponential generating function given by
$$g_{exp}(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}i(n) \frac {z^n}{n!}\tag{6}$$
This can be calculated using $(5) to give
$$\begin{align}g_{exp}(z) &=+1-\log (4)\\
&+ 2 \left(z \psi ^{(0)}(z+1)-z \psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{z}{2}+1\right)\right)\end{align}\tag{7}$$
The asymptotic behaviour is
$$\begin{align}g_{exp}(z\to 0)&\simeq 1-\log (4)\\&+\frac{\pi ^2 z^2}{6}-\frac{3}{2}  z^3 \zeta (3)+O(z^4)\end{align}\tag{8a}$$
$$\begin{align}g_{exp}(z\to \infty)&\simeq -\log (4)+z \log (4)\\&+\frac{1}{2 z}-\frac{1}{4 z^3}+O(\frac{1}{z^5})\end{align}\tag{8b}$$
A nice formula related to $(3)$ is for $-1 \lt t \lt 1$
$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^t}{(x+1)^2} \, dx=\pi  t \csc (\pi  t)\tag{9}$$

@Martin R yes, thank you, have clarified my writing.

Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Note that we have for $n>1$
$$\begin{align}
i(n)&=\int_0^1 \log^n\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\,dx\tag1\\\\
&=2\int_0^1 \frac{\log^n(x)}{(1+x)^2}\,dx\tag2\\\\
&=2\left.\frac{d^n}{dt^n}\left(\int_0^1\frac{x^t}{(1+x)^2}\,dx\right)\right|_{t=0}\tag3\\\\
&=2\left.\frac{d^n}{dt^n}\left(t\int_0^1\frac{x^{t-1}}{1+x}\,dx\right)\right|_{t=0}\tag4\\\\
&=2\left.\frac{d^n}{dt^n}\left(t\sum_{m=0}^\infty (-1)^m\int_0^1x^{t+m-1}\,dx\right)\right|_{t=0}\tag5\\\\
&=2\left.\frac{d^n}{dt^n}\left(t\sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^m\int_0^1x^{t+m-1}\,dx\right)\right|_{t=0}\tag6\\\\
&=2\left.\frac{d^n}{dt^n}\left(t\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m+t}\right)\right|_{t=0}\tag7\\\\
&=2n\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}}\left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m+t}\right)\right|_{t=0}\tag8\\\\
&=(-1)^{n-1} 2n(n-1)!\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m^{n}}\tag9\\\\
&=(-1)^{n} 2n!\left(1-2^{1-n}\right)\zeta(n)\tag{10}
\end{align}$$


NOTES:
In going from $(1)$ to $(2)$, we enforced the substitution $\frac{1-x}{1+x}\mapsto x$.
In going from $(2)$ to $(3)$, we used $\frac{d}{dt}x^t=x^t\log(x)$ $n$ times.
In going from $(3)$ to $(4)$, we integrated by parts with $u=x^t$ and $v=\frac1{1+x}$
In going from $(4)$ to $(5)$, we used the power series representation for $\frac1{1+x}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty (-1)^m x^m$ for $0\le x<1$.
In going from $(5)$ to $(6)$, we noted that the result from the first term of the series is $0$.
In going from $(6)$ to $(7)$, we carried out the integral.
In going from $(7)$ to $(8)$, we used Leibnitz's rule for product differentiation.
In going from $(8)$ to $(9)$, we carried out the $n-1$ derivatves and evaluated the result at $t=0$.
In going from $(9)$ to $(10)$, we used the expression for $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m^n}=-(1-2^{1-n})\zeta(n)$ in terms of the Riemann Zeta function.  This can be derived easily by writing the series in terms of even and odd terms and adding the result to the series representation of the Riemann Zeta function.

@ Mark Viola: excellent solution, nicely laid out step by step. It is even valid in the limits $n\to 0$ and $n\to 1$. Nothing to improve except for a sign change which has crept in between (5) and (6).

@Dr.WolfgangHintze Thank you for the very nice note!  And pleased to hear that this solution was clear.  Just curious ... What sign change do you belive occurred between $(5)$ and $(6)$?  Note that in $(5)$ the first term in the series (i.e., the $m=0$ term) is $\frac1t$.  Hence after multiplying by $t$, this term is independent of $t$.  Since we will be differentiating, this term is superfluous.   In $(6)$, we simply ignore this term and begin the series at $m=1$.  Let me know if this is clear.

@ Mark Viola. The sign of your result (10) is wrong (e.g. for n=2 the integral is positive),  and I found, where the error occured.

@Dr.WolfgangHintze Ah.  There sign error occured at the very last step.  I've edited accordingly.

Substitute $t= \frac {1-x}{1+x}$
\begin{align}&\int_{0}^{1} \ln^n\frac {1-x}{1+x}\;dx\\
=&\ 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^n t}{(1+t)^2}dt
=2\int_0^1 {\ln^n t}\ d\left(\frac t{1+t}\right)\\
\overset{ibp}=&-2 n\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^{n-1} t}{1+t}dt
=2(-1)^n\left(1-\frac1{2^{n-1}} \right)n!\ \text{Li}_n(1)
\end{align}

@ Quanto: Very good solution, which excels for its brevitiy, and purity as it remains in the domain of polylogs (not switching to Zeta). It was hard for me to tell which solution I should accept. In the end I slightly preferred that of Mark Viola due to his extensive derivation.
